# Pass tags from CLI to Pytest-bdd and execute specific scenarios

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pytest, fixtures

Tags(smoke/regression) to be passed from CLI and to be interpreted in conftest.py to execute those scenarios satisfying the tags.

I've looked into the pytest-bdd document [here](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest-bdd/blob/a8795dad7836f96a2074dc005206ffcd2d08ba75/README.rst#organizing-your-scenarios)  and failed to find the connection.

Scenario Outline has: (as python decorators can be stacked)

```
@pytest.mark.smoke
Scenario Outline: "VALID" Test

@pytest.mark.smoke
@pytest.mark.regression
  Scenario Outline: "INVALID" Test

@pytest.mark.regression
  Scenario Outline: "MIXED" Test
```

conftest.py

```
def pytest_bdd_apply_tag(tag, function):    
    if 'smoke' not in tag:  #what should I use to take values from CLI and execute those
        marker = pytest.mark.skip # skips scenario where 'smoke' is not marked
        marker(function)
        return True
    return None
```

The above code in conftest.py skips all scenarios. 
CLI Input:

`pytest --env='qa' -m 'smoke'`

where `pytest_addoption` is used for `--env='qa'` and `pytest_bdd_apply_tag` for `-m`.

We want to execute only scenarios that have marked smoke(VALID & INVALID) when I pass smoke; scenarios that have marked regression(INVALID & MIXED) when I pass regression and default smoke when I don't pass any parameter in CLI via -m option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My bad, I was wondering how I got mislead by the pytest markers with the scenario tag lines as mentioned in the documentation.

The changes I made on feature file is

```
@smoke
Scenario Outline: "VALID" Test

@smoke @regression
  Scenario Outline: "INVALID" Test

@regression
  Scenario Outline: "MIXED" Test
```

I've eliminated the `pytest_bdd_apply_tag` method from conftest.py.

Giving this in the command line works for me

```
pytest -m "regression" --env="uat"
```